Amazon Aurora vs PostgreSQL / MySQL eventual consistency
When compraing failover read replicas between Amazon Aurora and other options, it seems like the Amazon Aurora has only eventual consistency option [1], while other options have ability to create a standby replica that has synchronous replication with the master [2].
Is it true? Why isn't Amazon Aurora doesn't have an option for sync replication? In case my master DB fails I will loose some data with Amazon Aurora, while with other options, seems like all data will be preserved.


When data is written to the primary DB instance, Aurora synchronously replicates the data across Availability Zones to six storage nodes associated with your cluster volume.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Concepts.AuroraHighAvailability.html

